# browser back button vs refresh button

Tags: browser, back-button, page-refresh

Scenario 1: let say the previous page that i visited is example.com, so if i hit the back button, the browser will load example.com

Scenario 2: let say i am currently on example.com and hit the refresh/reload button, the browser will load example.com

My question: in the browser point of view, does it differentiate the two scenario and do anything differently? is there a spec for this?

My suspicion is that the browser does differentiate these 2 scenario. In my case, example.com is a static single page react app that do fetch request onComponentDidMount. I got a Status Code: 304 Not Modified when click refresh/reload button and Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache) when click back button.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between refresh and back is that the browser understands the back button as completely new access. Refresh is something little bit different. For example, in back button result, you won't get 304 status.